# Is there any alternative of duckling?

Tags: rasa-nlu, duckling

Rasa v 0.15 change log states that "`SpacyEntityExtractor` supports same entity filtering as `DucklingHTTPExtractor`" but if sentence has ‘time’ entity then values identified by spacy entity extractor are just the text values(ex. `7pm`) and not the real time values (ex `2019-05-03T07.00.00`) as identified by duckling.

Answer (score 0):

Duckling is indeed the [recommended option](https://blog.rasa.com/rasa-nlu-in-depth-part-2-entity-recognition/) for dates. 
Is there any reason why you don't want to use Duckling?

You could also implement a [custom NLU pipeline component](https://blog.rasa.com/enhancing-rasa-nlu-with-custom-components/), if you want to use a another library.